# How can I run a script on a Unix box without enough space to store it?

Tags: embedded, telnet

Specifically what I'd like to do is run screenfetch on my router, just for fun.

Here's my disk space free:

```
admin@RT-N66W:/tmp/home/root# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                30336     30336         0 100% /
tmpfs                   119880       448    119432   0% /tmp
devfs                   119880         0    119880   0% /dev
/dev/mtdblock4             768       472       296  61% /jffs
```

Here are my options in /bin:

```
admin@RT-N66W:/tmp/home/root# ls /bin/
ash               comgt             echo              ionice            more              ping              sed               umount
booster           cp                egrep             kill              mount             ping6             sh                uname
booster_watchdog  date              fgrep             ln                mv                ps                sleep             usleep
busybox           dd                fsync             login             netstat           pwd               sync              vi
cat               df                grep              ls                nice              rm                tar               watch
chmod             dmesg             gunzip            mkdir             nvram             rmdir             touch             wps_monitor
chown             eapd              gzip              mknod             pidof             rstats            true              zcat
```

The only way I can connect to it, AFAIK, is through telnet. The script I'd like to run is 232kb and I only have 120kb available. Would I be able to mount another device, like my laptop, and run the script from there, with these tools? Or is there some other way to run it?

Comment: Can you compress the script and then execute it with `zcat yourscript | ash`?

Comment: I don't use telnet, but you should be able to pipe it from the local end. You only need one command at a time on the remove. What tools do you have at your end?